# Changing css attribute value with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

This one is bit harder than

```
$('a').css('color','#ff6600');
```

I am making a styleswitcher that must manipulate head a element css attribute

```
<head>
HEAD TAGS
<style type="text/css">
a{color:#ff6600;}
 </style>
</head>
```

Reason why I cannot use $.css() is because  it manipulates inline css style of any given a element on the page thus overriding for example   menu hover link color or any other link color that is not originally  ff6600.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So you want it to apply to any `a` element that does not have a specific override with another CSS selector?

Comment: exactly , I must manipulate a{color:#ff6600;}<-- that value directly ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your new CSS to the head.  Since you mentioned in your comment you want to switch it as the user changes it, you can create a style with an ID and then update it:

```
$("<style id='customStyle'></style>").appendTo("head");
$("#switcher").click(function () {
    var r=Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
    var g=Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
    var b=Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
    $("#customStyle").text("a {color:rgb(" + r + ", " + g + "," + b + ");}");});
```

See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/wdAGh/3/

Comment: nice one!, but again an issue ,  I cannot position it correctly, and I am using a tinycolor.js to have visitors change the colors , so once they start sliding that thing they end up with hundreds of styles, unless :) can we add an id to style tag ?  must try this

Comment: add an id to style tag ? Why do that ?

Comment: than I can delete and load new one once they use tinicolor.js http://bgrins.github.io/TinyColor/

Comment: I updated the fiddle / code to reflect an example where the color changes on every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be needing the functions from [this article](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript):

- **`getCSSRule()`**: gets a CSS rule. You can edit it:

  ```
  var aCSS = getCSSRule('a'); // get the 'a' rule you mentioned.
  aCSS.style.color = 'green'; // change its color to green
  aCSS.style.textDecoration='underline overline'; // change it a little more
  ```
- **`killCSSRule()`**: Deletes a CSS rule -- any objects on the page with that style will instantly become unstyled.

  ```
  killCSSRule('a');
  ```
- **`addCSSRule()`**: straightforward: creates a new CSS rule.

  ```
  var someDiv = addCSSRule('#someDiv');
  someDiv.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
  ```

**[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/GvZYV/1/)** for the functions' codes and some usage example. Don't forget to check the article for details: [Totally Pwn CSS with Javascript](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript).

Answer (score 0):

You have to identify your link with an `ID` (or class of links with `class`), then you can target them more efficiently with jQuery, so your code must be like that:

```
<head>
    <!-- HEAD TAGS -->
    <style type="text/css">
       a{color:#ff6600;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="link1" href="#"> LINK 1</a>
    <a id="link2" href="#"> LINK 2</a>
</body>
```

Now, if you wanna only target `LINK 1`, you can do this in jQuery:

```
$('a#link1').css('color','#ff6600');
```

Comment: I am not trying to target specific id or class as explained above